# How do I remove wifi functionality?

Tags: wireless

I have wifi on my 10.04 machine, but I have no use for it. This command will disable it on startup

```
/usr/bin/dbus-send --system --type=method_call \
--dest=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop \
/NetworkManager org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set \
string:org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
string:WirelessEnabled variant:boolean:false
```

However, when the machine wakes up from suspend, the wifi comes back on. I have tried to put the above command in a script in /etc/pm/sleep.d but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

What about adding something like this

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:01:23:45:67:89:AB
# the mac address is only an example
```

to /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf, or blacklisting the wifi kernel module?

Comment: I've tried both these suggestions but neither works. For the second I added `blacklist rt3090` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and rebooted. I used to have a driver from a ppa for this and I uninstalled  it, but after a recent kernel update the wifi returned.

Comment: `lsmod` says `rt3090sta 674216 1`

Comment: I added `blacklist rt3090sta` instead and that worked. Confusingly, `lshw` said the driver was called  `rt3090`

Comment: As an aside: `powertop` still says `A USB device is active 100.0% of the time:
USB device  2-6 : 2.4G Multimedia Wireless Kit (Chicony)`. I don't have any other wifis and nothing is connected to the usb.

Answer (score 0):

Does your system have a wifi kill switch on it?  If so, you can tape the switch to the "Off" position, which will deactivate your wifi until you turn kill switch back to the operating position.

Comment: You can also turn it off at the BIOS level. Without specifics of the machine, there's no way to tell exactly how to do it.

Comment: I don't have a bios switch